# Proof of Proposition 2.27 in Diamond, Darmon, Taylor's "Fermat's Last Theorem"

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, galois-cohomology

See page 67 of the free online text for Proposition 2.27 below. All cohomology is Galois cohomology. Page 62 defines goodness, ordinaryness, and semistability.  Page 65-66 defines $H^1_f$. The notation $\operatorname{ad} \rho$ refers to $\operatorname{End}(M_\rho)$, where $M_\rho$ is the module underlying the representation $\rho$, and $\operatorname{ad}^0 \rho$ refers to trace-zero endomorphisms. The notation $G_\ell$ refers to the local Galois group at $\ell$.

**Proposition 2.27**

Suppose that $\overline{\rho}: G_{\ell} \to \operatorname{GL}_2(k)$ is semistable (meaning flat or ordinary). Then

$$\left| H^1_f(G_{\ell}, \operatorname{ad}^0 \overline{\rho}) \right| \leq \left| H^0(G_{\ell}, \operatorname{ad}^0 \overline{\rho})\right| \left|k\right|$$

The given proof apparently uses the following result of Fontaine:

**Proposition 2.28**: Suppose that $\rho: G_\ell \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathcal O/\lambda^n)$ is good (i.e. flat, more or less). Then

$$\left| H^1_f(G_\ell, \operatorname{ad} \rho)\right| = \left| H^0(G_\ell, \operatorname{ad}^0 \rho)\right| (\left| \mathcal O/\lambda^n \right|)^2$$

Here $\mathcal O$ is a complete Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\lambda$ and residue field $k$. Here is the how proof goes assuming 2.28:

Note that if $\rho: G_{\ell} \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathcal O/\lambda^n)$ is good, then

$$H^1(G_\ell/I_\ell) \subset H^1_f(G_\ell, \operatorname{ad} \rho) \cap H^1(G_\ell, \mathcal O/\lambda^n)$$

by Lemma 2.22 d), which gives the result.

I do not understand this proof. Specifically:

1. Why does goodness of $\rho$ give us the desired containment?
2. Where did we use 2.28?
3. Most importantly, why does the result follow from the given containment? I read Lemma 2.22 d), and it essentially just says if two modules are $\mathbb Z_\ell[I_\ell]$-isomorphic, then one is good iff the other one is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\overline{\rho}$ is good. Note that $\operatorname{ad}\overline{\rho}=\operatorname{ad}^0\overline{\rho} \oplus k$.

By the definition of $H^1_f$, it follows that $H^1_f(G_{\ell},\operatorname{ad}^0\overline{\rho})$ is the kernel of the map $H^1_f(G_{\ell},\operatorname{ad}\overline{\rho}) \rightarrow H^1(G_{\ell},k)$ (given by the trace map $\operatorname{ad}\overline{\rho} \rightarrow k$).

The domain has cardinality $|H^1_f(G_{\ell},\operatorname{ad}\overline{\rho})|= |H^0(G_{\ell},\operatorname{ad}^0\overline{\rho})||k|^2$, so it’s enough to show that the map is not zero (since it’s $k$-linear).

The trick is to see that this image contains $H^1(G_{\ell}/I_{\ell},k)$, which is nonzero. Indeed, $k$ is a direct factor of $\operatorname{ad}\overline{\rho}$ and unramified cocycles are flat (that may follow from Lemma 2.22(d)).

If I’m not mistaken, they would correspond to  extensions of the form $M_{\rho} \otimes k^{\oplus 2}$, where $G_{\ell}$ acts on $k^{\oplus 2}$ in an unramified way and the Frobenius is a unipotent matrix.

With a good enough formalism for mod $\ell$ representations (which may or may not currently exist), I would expect that $H^1_f(G_{\ell},\operatorname{ad}\overline{\rho}) = H^1_f(G_{\ell},\operatorname{ad}^0\overline{\rho}) \oplus H^1_f(G_{\ell},k)$, and that the flat $k$-valued cocycles be exactly the unramified ones.

Comment: Great answer. Since you have answered a few of my questions recently, I am wondering if we could have an extended chat elsewhere.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why it is enough to check that the map is nonzero? If it were, the kernel would be the entire domain, and so we would be off by a factor of the cardinality of $k$. I assume the fact that the kernel is a proper $k$-subspace is how we conclude?

Comment: That’s the idea: basically, one has $|\ker|=|H^1_f|/|\mathrm{im}|=\mathrm{bound} \cdot |k|/|\mathrm{im}|$, so we have the bound iff $|\mathrm{im}| \geq |k|$. Since $\mathrm{im}$ is a $k$-vector space, $|\mathrm{im}| \geq |k|$ iff $\mathrm{im}$ is nonzero (ie iff the map is nonzero).